# Laravel - creating a repository for Sentry

Tags: laravel, filter, cartalyst-sentry

I want to make a user repository which uses Sentry for user management. All goes well, however, I can't use the repository in `filters.php`.

If I use the regular `Sentry::check()` method in my `sentry` route filter, I cannot perform any authentication actions on the user. I think its because the user repository and plain `Sentry` are two different things and do not share anything in common.

My question: how can I use my own custom user repository in `filters.php`? I simply don't know how to make laravel aware of the repository in the filters file.